# Find out is a generic type implement an interface

Tags: c#, generics

In the method below is there a way to know if the type `T` implement a specific interface `IMyInterface2`

```
public IList<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class, IMyInterface1
{

   return myResult;
}
```

**Update :**

Then I use like this

```
MyMethod<MyClass>();
```

Myclass implement `IMyInterface1` and `IMyInterface2`

```
MyMethod<MyClassB>();
```

Myclass implement `IMyInterface1` and **NOT** `IMyInterface2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is:

```
public IList<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class, IMyInterface1
{
    if (typeof(IMyInterface2).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        // code here
    }

    return myResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as with any other object, except you have to use `typeof` instead of `.GetType()`:

```
var implements = typeof(IMyInterface2).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```